# Validation message not working in Thymeleaf

Tags: java, twitter-bootstrap, validation, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I am new at Java. Using Thymeleaf and Spring-Boot.

Trying to show validation message on wrong input.

"Phone" property must be between 7 to 13 character long. Validation message will be shown if rules are not followed.

Please note, validation works but message is not shown.

Here is the Model

```
@Entity
public class Author {

@Column(name = "phone")
@Size(min=7, max = 13, message = "The category name must be {min} to {max} characters in length.")
private String phone;
}
```

the Controller

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/author")
public class AuthorController extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

@Autowired
AuthorService authorService;

@Override
public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addViewController("/new-author").setViewName("newauthor");
}

@RequestMapping(value="/new-author", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String newAuthor(Model model){

    Author author = new Author();
    model.addAttribute("addNewAuthor", author);

    return "newauthor";
}

@RequestMapping(value="/new-author", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String newAuthor(@Valid  Author author, BindingResult bindingResult, Model model){

    model.addAttribute("addNewAuthor", author);

    if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
        return "newauthor";
    }

    try{

        authorService.createAuthor(author);
        model.addAttribute("statusReport", "Author Saved");
    }

    catch (Exception e){

        model.addAttribute("statusReport", "Author not Saved");
    }

    return "newauthor";
}
}
```

here is the View

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
<title>Add Author</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../public/bootstrap-3.3.6-     dist/css/bootstrap.css" th:href="@{/bootstrap-3.3.6-dist/css/bootstrap.css}"/>

</head>
<body>
<h1>Add New Author</h1>
<div class="col-lg-3" >
<form role="form" action="#" th:action="@{/author/new-author}"  th:object="${addNewAuthor}" method="post">


<div th:class="form-group" th:classappend="${#fields.hasErrors('phone')}? 'has-error'">
    <label>Phone</label>
    <input class="form-control" type="text" th:field="*{phone}" placeholder="Enter author's phone number"/>
    <p th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('phone')}" class="label label-danger" th:errors="*{phone}">Phone Error</p>
</div>

<button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Add</button>
<button type="reset" class="btn btn-default">Reset</button>

<p th:text="${statusReport}" > </p>
</form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `addNewAuthor` should have the `@ModelAttribute` annotation.
It should be :

```
 public String newAuthor(
    @Valid @ModelAttribute("addNewAuthor") Author author, 
    BindingResult bindingResult, 
    Model model) {
    // ...
 }
```

Comment: It's been years already but this helped me a lot. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I suppose it's better to do it this way,
first, remove `message` from `Size` constraint

```
   @Column(name = "phone")
   @Size(min=7, max = 13)
   private String phone;
```

Second, add message to the localization file (`message.properties`).

```
Size.author.phone=The category name must be {1} to {2} characters in length.
```

Another way :

```
@Column(name = "phone")
@Size(min=7, max = 13, message="{phone.size}")
private String phone;
```

In `message.properties` :

```
phone.size=The category name must be {1} to {2} characters in length.
```